# Unable to use custom class in a protocol with @objc attribute?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, protocols

I am trying to create a protocol for JSON loading delegation, `JSONLoaderDelegate`. My other class, called `JSONLoader`, is supposed to dispatch events to its delegate (that implements the `JSONLoaderDelegate` protocol) like:

```
self?.delegate?.jsonLoaderdidEndWithError(self!, error: JSONLoaderError.LoadError)
```

The implementation of the JSONLoader is not that important (imho). However I seem to have problems to implement the protocol, this is the code:

```
@objc protocol JSONLoaderDelegate {

    optional func jsonLoaderdidBeginLoading(jsonLoader: JSONLoader)
    func jsonLoaderdidEndWithError(jsonLoader: JSONLoader, error: JSONLoader.JSONLoaderError)
    func jsonLoaderDidEndWithSuccess(jsonLoader: JSONLoader)

}
```

This looks pretty straightforward to me but I am getting an error:

> method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot
>   be represented in Objective-C.

pointed to all three functions.

Obviously, if I remove the `@objc` attribute I cannot use the `optional` for the function. I would really like to keep `jsonLoaderdidBeginLoading` as optional tho. Any ideas / ways to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the 3 methods have in common is the `JSONLoader` parameter, and that's what I think prevents you from bridging the protocol. In order to solve the problem you have to make it objc compatible.

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct, or at least that's how I see it. However, how do I make it objc compatible? Do I just add "@objc" in front of "class JSONLoader"?

Comment: Add @objc to its declaration... and fix all things needed to make it compatible (no generics, for instance). In the end it might be the wrong approach.... just to have an optional func in a protocol. It's a trade off, and it's up to you which of the 2 options is better (objc compatible or no optional func)

Comment: Yeah, I see I cannot make an enum @objc compatible. I guess I will just get rid of that optional then. Oh well... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Fygo You can get around the enum problem by declaring it in a C header file and bridging it to Swift *or* using the latest Xcode beta since Swift 1.2 supports `@objc` for basic enums: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22

Answer (score 8):

I faced this problem as I had a class `MyConnection` that had no parent class. 
Like this.

```
public class MyConnection {
}
```

I can't put `@objc` before this, as I get a warning

> Only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc

So I changed the class to be inherited from `NSObject`.
Like this

```
public class MyConnection: NSObject {
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error. `method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C.`

I changed the syntax to the following in swift 2.0. It works fine now!

```
@objc protocol AppModelDelegate {
    optional func compititorList(com:[Competitor]!)
}

class Competitor:NSObject{
    var id:Int?
    var title:String?
}
```

Note: the Competitor class type changed to NSObject which cleared the delegate rule violation

Also in the case of NSJSON parsing. I changed to the following.

```
if (_httpStatusCode == 200) {
    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var error : NSError?
    print("responseString : \(responseString) ")

    var service_result:NSDictionary =  NSDictionary()
    do {
        let anyObj = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
        service_result = anyObj
    } catch let error as ErrorType {
        print("json error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONLoaderError.LoadError
```

Is this an enum type? You cannot convert Swift enums to Obj-C code. You'll need to use an int instead.