# Method cannot be a member of an @objc protocol after i remove tuple

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use Swift `protocol` in Objective-C.

Firstly it was using `tuple` like this:

```
protocol Validation {
    func validate(value:String?) -> (Bool, ValidationErrorType)
}
```

and because tuples are not suitable for Objective-C i decide to use `Dictionary` for that.

```
@objc protocol Validation {
    func validate(value:String?) -> [NSNumber : ValidationErrorType]
}
```

And the result is :

> Method cannot be a member of an @objc protocol because its result type cannot be represented in Objective-C

Could you please share you're opinion about what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: What is `ValidationErrorType`?

Comment: ValidationErrorType it is enum : int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method have `ValidationErrorType` as a result with `Dictionary`, and that's I think preventing you from bridging the protocol. To solve the problem you have to make it `objc` compatible or change the return value to directly `NSDictionary` like this.

```
@objc protocol Validation {
    func validate(value:String?) -> NSDictionary
}
```

Comment: But in this case i have problem with return statement that do now what to return enum types

Comment: You can return enum integer for that, read this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28838918/6433023)