# How to use the delegate Swift from the Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a `viewcontroller` in `Swift` that works well, and I would like to use it from an `Objective-C` class. My problem is that I don't know how to use it.

I try to add the delegate in the header of my main Objective-C class.

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <PlanningSearchDelegate>
```

But I think as it is a swift class, it doesn't work. The error is:
**Cannot find protocol declaration for PlanningSearchDelegate**

Then, I tried to add the `@objc` word in the swift class.

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol PlanningSearchDelegate
{
    func planningSearchDidSelectResult(_ result:DALSearchResult)
}

class PlanningSearchViewController: UIViewController 
{
}

extension PlanningSearchViewController: UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let result = _results[indexPath.row]
        delegate?.planningSearchDidSelectResult(result)
    }
}
```

But I have an error message:

**Method cannot be a member of an @objc protocol because the type of the parameter cannot be represented in Objective-C.**

I put the `delegate = self` in the `prepareForSegue` of the main `Objective-C` class without success :

```
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showSearchViewSegue"])
{
    PlanningSearchViewController *searchViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    searchViewController.delegate = self;
}
```

The error message is:
**Property 'delegate' not found on object of type "PlanningSearchViewController *'**

Here is the `DALSearchResult` Class :

import Foundation

```
class DALSearchResult
{
    var contactId: Int
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
    var email: String
    var phone: String
    var city: String
    var registrationId: Int?
    var slotId: Int?
    var vehicleId: Int?
    var startDate: Date?
    var vehicleName: String?

    init(contactId:Int, firstname:String, lastname:String, email:String, phone:String, city:String)
    {
        self.contactId = contactId
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone
        self.city = city
    }

    convenience init(registrationId:Int, slotId:Int, vehicleId:Int, contactId:Int, firstname:String, lastname:String, email:String, phone:String, city:String, startDate:Date, vehicleName: String)
    {
        self.init(contactId: contactId, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, email: email, phone: phone, city: city)

        self.registrationId = registrationId
        self.vehicleId = vehicleId
        self.slotId = slotId
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.vehicleName = vehicleName
    }
}
```

Anyone has an idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `DALSearchResult `?

Comment: It is a class I call in the swift that contain informations on the concerning search of people (firstname, lastname, phone, email, etc...)

Comment: add/show the class code too.

Comment: quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838433/unable-to-use-custom-class-in-a-protocol-with-objc-attribute // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256261/swift-2-0-method-cannot-be-marked-objc-because-the-type-of-the-parameter-cannot

Comment: try `class DALSearchResult: NSObject`

Comment: I put the DALSearchResult in the message just now.

Comment: It accepts the delegate now. It crashes in another place now with that error message: [MainViewController planningSearchDidSelectResult:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: 1. does your `MainViewController ` implements protocol method `planningSearchDidSelectResult`? >> 2. Does this `if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showSearchViewSegue"])` gets called? 3. How `delegate` var declared?

Comment: Ok that was the problem :D Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share how the declaration of `DALSearchResult` looks like? Maybe it's an enum which cannot be translated to Obj-C. In this case you might need to pass the `result` in a different way.

Comment: I declare it like this : var results:[DALSearchResult] = [], I put it in the message just now.

Comment: As others suggested, just try `@objc class DALSearchResult: NSObject` where you define your class.

Comment: I put it, it is better, it accepts the class DALSearchResult declaration now, but now it puts me another message : [MainViewController planningSearchDidSelectResult:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. The mainviewController is my main objective-C class

Comment: Are you actually implementing the method in `MainViewController`?

Answer (score 2):

Make DALSearchResult class Objective-C compatible. If your DALSearchResult does not extend from NSObject, you can extend it form NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

To access swift from objective-C you have to import the swift.h always in your class that you want to use it like so

```
#import "Yourprojectname-Swift.h"
```